# Views PHP and Webform submissions problem

Tags: views, webforms

I am creating a view of submitted data from webform. I was able to create it properly. Next step is to filter the data based on their dates, since webform stores date submitted data as strings, I use Views PHP to convert the date to integer and use that value for the comparison. It was properly filtered, but I am encountering a LOT of notices in view:

Notice: Undefined property: webform_handler_field_submission_data::$webform_node in webform_handler_field_submission_data->render() (line 176 of ...\modules\webform\views\webform_handler_field_submission_data.inc).

how do i remove these notices/errors - need your help! would appreciate your help. thanks in advance.